# tracking directory permission changes

Tags: logs, chmod, audit, dump, linux-audit

Permission of a certain directory named 11203 got changed twice because of which the hosted app encountered some problems.

When I used the command:

```
ausearch -i |grep chmod |grep 11203
```

I got the below result

```
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(12/16/2014 17:15:36.201:68342) : user pid=19247 uid=enginst auid=enginst ses=4229 msg='cwd=/apps/oradump/ora_temp_rdbms/OH3 cmd=chmod -R 777 11203 terminal=pts/2 res=success'
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(12/16/2014 17:36:33.968:68753) : user pid=1801 uid=enginst auid=enginst ses=4229 msg='cwd=/apps/oracle/RDBMS cmd=chmod -R 777 11203 terminal=pts/2 res=success'
```

Though I can understand a bit in the above output, I still have few questions.

Does the above say that the command chmod has been ran by the user enginst as a direct command in the terminal, or could it be initiated by some process which was in turn started by enginst user?

Both the pid's in the result are not found in the "ps aux" outputs. Were these pid's the pid of the command "chmod"?

What can be done to enable more logging, so that this issue can be nailed down.

I have started psacct process, assuming that it will have records of which process the pid referred to and so on.

Found from another link that the below command will give us info about pid even if the process has already been completed and are not in "ps aux" output.

```
dump-acct /var/account/pacct | awk -F '|' '$10 ~ / 31652 / {print}'
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case, as I didn't get any results for the above command, even after giving a valid pid (pid of process which is completed)

Can someone clarify? Thank you.

Comment: For more instantaneous logging when this actually occurs you may try the inotify program. It is able to directly alert you when a certain file/directory/inode is changed. Either changed in contents, attributes, created, etc..

Comment: Could you check the user “enginst”’s history record?